# Ruby Koans Scoring Project

Tags: ruby

I'm working through the Ruby Koans, and I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out what is going wrong with a method I've written. I'm in about_scoring_project.rb, and I've written the score method for the dice game:

```
def score(dice)
  return 0 if dice == []
  sum = 0
  rolls = dice.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |result, element| result[element] += 1; result; }
  rolls.each { |key, value| 
    # special condition for rolls of 1
    if key == 1  
      sum += 1000 | value -= 3 if value >= 3
      sum += 100*value
      next
    end
    sum += 100*key | value -= 3 if value >= 3
    sum += 50*value if key == 5 && value > 0
  }
  return sum
end
```

For those unfamiliar with the exercise:

> Greed is a dice game where you roll up to five dice to accumulate
>   points.  The following "score" function will be used to calculate the
>   score of a single roll of the dice.
>
> A greed roll is scored as follows:
>
> - A set of three ones is 1000 points
> - A set of three numbers (other than ones) is worth 100 times the   number. (e.g. three fives is 500 points).
> - A one (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 100 points.
> - A five (that is not part of a set of three) is worth 50 points.
> - Everything else is worth 0 points.
>
> Examples:
>
> score([1,1,1,5,1]) => 1150 points score([2,3,4,6,2]) => 0 points
>   score([3,4,5,3,3]) => 350 points score([1,5,1,2,4]) => 250 points
>
> More scoring examples are given in the tests below:
>
> Your goal is to write the score method.

I run into trouble when I try to run the last test in the file: `assert_equal 550, score([5,5,5,5])`

For some reason I am returning 551 instead of 550. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I had trouble on that test too. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you're really adding the result of a `|` operator (Bitwise OR) to the total score:

```
sum += 100*key | value -= 3 if value >= 3 # This is 501 in your case
```

Proof:

```
irb(main):004:0> value = 4
=> 4
irb(main):005:0> 100 * 5 | value -= 3 # This should be read as (500) | 1 which is 501
=> 501
```

So rewrite it like this:

```
if value >= 3
  sum += 100 * key
  value -= 3
end
```

Answer (score 6):

My approach uses two lookup tables - one containing the scores for triples, the other for singles. I work out the score for each number using the tables, and accumulate the total using `inject`:

```
def score(dice)
  triple_scores = [1000, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
  single_scores = [100, 0, 0, 0, 50, 0]
  (1..6).inject(0) do |score, number|
    count = dice.count(number)
    score += triple_scores[number - 1] * (count / 3)
    score += single_scores[number - 1] * (count % 3)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is my approach:

```
def score(dice)
  # Count how many what
  clusters = dice.reduce(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, num| hash[num] += 1; hash }

  # Since 1's are special, handle them first
  ones = clusters.delete(1) || 0
  score = ones % 3 * 100 + ones / 3 * 1000

  # Then singular 5's
  score += clusters[5] % 3 * 50

  # Then the triples other than triple-one
  clusters.reduce(score) {|s, (num, count)| s + count / 3 * num * 100 }
end
```

Comment: While your code succeeds for the koans, it fails with (for example) [1,5,1,5,1]. By taking a naive count of ones, any three ones are assumed to be worth 1000 when in fact, in this case they are worth 100 each so the answer is 400 but your code gives 1100.

Comment: The rules do not stipulate that a set of three must be contiguous. :-)

Answer (score 4):

I went with

```
def score(dice)
  dice.uniq.map do |die|
    count = dice.count die
    if count > 2
      count -= 3
      die == 1 ? 1000 : 100 * die
    else 0
    end + case die
          when 1 then count * 100
          when 5 then count * 50
          else 0
          end
  end.inject(:+) || 0
end
```

Answer (score 2):

My approach:

```
     def score(dice)
        score = 0
        score += dice.count(1) >= 3? (1000+ (dice.count(1) -3)*100): dice.count(1) * 100
        score += dice.count(5) >= 3 ? (500 + (dice.count(5) -3)*50): dice.count(5) * 50
       [2,3,4,6].each {|x| dice.count(x) >=3? score+= x*100:0}
       return score
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my answer:

```
def score(dice)
  frequency = dice.inject(Hash.new(0)) do |h, el|
    h[el] += 1
    h
  end

  score_triples = { 1 => 1000 }
  score_singles = { 1 => 100, 5 => 50 }

  score = 0
  frequency.each do |k, v|
    score += v / 3 * score_triples.fetch(k, 100 * k)
    score += v % 3 * score_singles.fetch(k, 0)
  end
  score
end
```

Answer (score 2):

This was the first piece of code I ever wrote by myself (With a ton of help of stackoverflow, of course.) After watching all other answers I realize it is way overkill specially because it works for a 9 numbers dice (does that exist?)

```
  def score(dice)
    
  if dice.empty?
    return 0
  end

  var_score = 0

  conteo = (0..9).to_a.each.map { |x| dice.count(x)} 
  
  #Evaluating 1
  if ( conteo[1] / 3 ) >= 0
    multiplier1 = conteo[1]/3
    var_score += multiplier1 * 1000
  end

  if ( conteo[1] % 3 ) != 0
    var_score += (conteo[1] % 3)*100
  end
  
  #Evaluating 5
  if ( conteo[5] % 3 ) != 0
    var_score += (conteo[5] % 3)* 50
  end

  #Evaluating numbers x 3    
  if (conteo[2..9].count { |x| x >= 3 }) > 0
    triplets = conteo[2..9].map {|x| x / 3}
    array_multiplicator = triplets.each_with_index.select {|num,index| (num > 0)}.map {|x| x[0]}
    product_triplets = triplets.each_with_index.select {|num,index| (num > 0)}.map {|x| x[1]}.map {|x| (x+2)*100}
    var_score += array_multiplicator.zip(product_triplets).map{|x| x.inject(&:*)}.sum
  end

  var_score
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It took 29 lines, but this is my first Ruby

```
    def score(dice)
      return 0 if dice == [] 
      sums = Array.new  # To hold number of occurrences 1 - 6
      for i in 0..6     # Initialize to 0... note [0] is not used 
        sums[i] = 0
      end
      total = 0   # To hold total
      dice.each do |dots|   # Number of dots showing on dice
        sums[dots] += 1     # Increment the array members 1 - 6
      end 
        if sums[1] > 2 then # If 3 1's
          total += 1000 
          sums[1] -= 3   # Remove the 3 you took, in case there's more
        end
        if sums[2] > 2  then total += 200  # If 3 2's
        end
        if sums[3] > 2  then total += 300   #If 3 3's
        end
        if sums[4] > 2  then total += 400    #If 3 4's
        end
        if sums[5] > 2  then total += 500     #If 3 5's
          sums[5] -= 3                        #Remove the 5's you took
        end
        if sums[6] > 2  then total += 600  #If 3 6's
        end
     total += (sums[1] * 100)   # If any ones are left
     total += (sums[5] * 50)    # Same for fives
     return total
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach was:

```
def score(dice)
  calculator = ->(no, group_multipler, individual_multipler) { (no / 3 * group_multipler) + (no % 3 * individual_multipler) }
  dice.group_by {|i| i % 7 }.inject(0) do |total, (value, scores)|
    group_multipler, individual_multipler = case value
    when 1
      [1000, 100]
    when 5
      [500, 50]
    else 
      [value * 100, 0]
    end
    total += calculator.call(scores.size, group_multipler, individual_multipler)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach used integer division and modulus division:

```
def score(dice)
    points = 1000 * (dice.count(1) / 3)
    points += 100 * (dice.count(1) % 3)
    points += 50 * (dice.count(5) % 3)
    (2..6).each do |i|
        points += (100 * i) * (dice.count(i) / 3)
    end
    points
end
```

Comment: I think this code would fail given: `[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]`, the score would be 1100 when in fact it should be 300. All count does is count the number of times something appears:

    # If a block is given, counts the number of elements for which the block
    # returns a true value.
    # 
    #    ary = [1, 2, 4, 2]
    #    ary.count                  #=> 4
    #    ary.count(2)               #=> 2
    #    ary.count { |x| x%2 == 0 } #=> 3

Answer (score 0):

This is my solutions.

```
def score(dice)
    score = 0
    # grab all the numbers and their amounts
    number_amounts = dice.reduce(Hash.new(0)) { |hash, numb| hash[numb] += 1; hash }

    # iterate through each pair
    number_amounts.each do |key, value|
      # case with number 1
      score += (value % 3) * 100 + value / 3 * 1000 if (key == 1)
      # case with number 5
      score += (value % 3) * 50 + value / 3 * key * 100 if (key == 5)
      # all numbers except 1 and 5
      score += (value / 3) * key * 100 if (key != 1 && key != 5)
    end
    score
end
```

Comment: Please do not post code only answers. Please explain what your code does.

Comment: Got it Dan-Dev. Added comments. I think now it look much better.

Answer (score 0):

```
    def score(dice)
  # Set up rules Hash
  rules = { 1 => {:triples => 1000, :singles => 100}, 5 => {:triples => 100, :singles => 50} }
  [2,3,4,6].each {|i| rules[i] = {:triples => 100, :singles => 0} }
  # Count all ocourencies
  counts = dice.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|e, h| h[e] += 1}

  #calculate total
  total = 0
  counts.each_pair{ | key, value | 
    total += value >= 3? (rules[key][:triples]*key + (value -3)*rules[key][:singles]): value * rules[key][:singles]
  }
  return total
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the new ruby enumerable method `tally`

```rb
def score(dice)
  return 0 if dice.empty?
  ans = dice.tally.map do |k,v|
    case k
    when 1
      three = (k * 1000) * (v/3)
      val = (v%3) * 100
      val + three 
    when 5
      three = (k * 100) * (v/3)
      val = (v%3) * 50
      val + three
    else
      (k * 100) * (v/3)
    end
  end 
  ans.reduce(0, :+)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt, feedback and refactoring suggestions most welcome:

```
def score(dice)
  score = 0
  score_array = [[0, 100, 200, 1000, 1100, 1200], [0, 0, 0, 200, 200, 200], [0, 0, 0, 300, 300, 300], [0, 0, 0, 400, 400, 400], [0, 50, 100, 500, 550, 600], [0, 0, 0, 600, 600, 600]]
  tally_hash = {1=>0, 2=>0, 3=>0, 4=>0, 5=>0, 6=>0}
  
  dice.sort.tally.each do |key, value|
    tally_hash[key] += value
  end

  tally_hash.each do |key, value|
    score += score_array[key -1][value]
  end
  return score
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I used hash for score

```
def score(dice)
  score_map = {
    1 => 100,
    5 => 50
  }
  cluster = dice.inject(Hash.new(0)) {|hash, num| hash[num] += 1; hash}

  cluster.inject(0) do |sum, (num, count)|
    set_count = count / 3

    sum += num == 1 ? 1000 * set_count : num * 100 * set_count
    sum + (score_map[num] || 0) * (count % 3)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I came up with. I'm still a rookie with Ruby.  Working through koans to help reinforce my understanding of the language.

```rb
def score(dice)
  # You need to write this method
  counts = [0,0,0,0,0,0]
  scores = [0,0,0,0,0,0]

  for die in dice
    dix = die - 1
    counts[dix]+=1
    scores[dix] = 0
    if counts[dix] >= 3
      scores[dix] = die * 100
      scores[dix] = 1000 if die == 1
    end
    scores[dix] += counts[dix] % 3 * 100 if die == 1
    scores[dix] += counts[dix] % 3 * 50 if die == 5
  end

  return scores.sum
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried a solution using strings and regex. Here is my code:

```
def score(dice)
  points = 0
  dicesorted = dice.sort!.join("")          # Turns 'dice' into a sorted string.
  if dicesorted[/(\d)\1\1/]                 # Look for a pattern of 3 repeating numbers using regex. $1 stores the "captured" value.
    points += 1000           if $1 == "1"   # Adds 1000 points if "1" is the repeating number.
    points +=  100 * $1.to_i if $1 != "1"   # Adds  100 points times the number's corresponding "integer value" otherwise.
    dicesorted.gsub!($1*3,"")               # Deletes the sequence of 3 repeating numbers from the string.
  end
  points += 100 * dicesorted.scan(/1/).size # If the remaing string has any "1" adds the number of occurences * 100 points.
  points +=  50 * dicesorted.scan(/5/).size # If the remaing string has any "5" adds the number of occurences *  50 points.
  points
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def score(dice)
    score = 0
    dice.uniq.each do |number|
        count = dice.count number
        weight = if number == 1 then 10 else number end
        if count >= 3
            score += weight * 100
            count -= 3
        end
        if count > 0 and number == 1 or number == 5
            score += count * weight * 10
        end
    end
    score
end
```

Answer (score -2):

```
def score(dice)
    ones = fives = rest = 0

    one_count = dice.count(1)
    if one_count > 2
        ones = 1000
        one_count -= 3
    end
    ones += one_count * 100

    five_count = dice.count(5)
    if five_count > 2
        fives = 500
        five_count -= 3
    end
    fives += five_count * 50

    [2,3,4,6].each do |num|
        if dice.count(num) > 2
            rest += num * 100
        end
    end

    return ones + fives + rest
end
```